# Azure Devops Release Pipeline - Azure App Service files not updated

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Azure App Service Deploy finishes successfully, but the files were not updated.

- I'm using the pipeline step version 4.*
- The WebApp.zip is retrieved successfully from the build and it contains the files, but in a strange subfolder structure: `Content\d_C\a\1\s\Platform\Backend\Backend.WebApp` (my path starts at 'Platform').

I already tried to use the WebApp release step, but it says it's not compatible with zip files.

This is the log output of the release step:

```
2019-05-21T13:09:43.6381219Z ##[section]Starting: Azure App Service Deploy: contras
2019-05-21T13:09:43.6498586Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-21T13:09:43.6498697Z Task         : Azure App Service Deploy
2019-05-21T13:09:43.6498814Z Description  : Update Azure App Services on Windows, Web App on Linux with built-in images or Docker containers, ASP.NET, .NET Core, PHP, Python or Node.js based Web applications, Function Apps on Windows or Linux with Docker Containers, Mobile Apps, API applications, Web Jobs using Web Deploy / Kudu REST APIs
2019-05-21T13:09:43.6498952Z Version      : 4.3.24
2019-05-21T13:09:43.6499008Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-05-21T13:09:43.6499078Z Help         : [More information](https://aka.ms/azurermwebdeployreadme)
2019-05-21T13:09:43.6499169Z ==============================================================================
2019-05-21T13:09:44.4804024Z Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'contras'
2019-05-21T13:09:44.9625484Z Updating App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"0"}
2019-05-21T13:09:58.0865664Z Updated App Service Application settings and Kudu Application settings.
2019-05-21T13:09:58.4962410Z [command]"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package='D:\a\r1\a\_MoonDesk Test\drop\WebApp.zip' -dest:auto,ComputerName='https://contras-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=contras',UserName='$contras__staging',Password='***',AuthType='Basic' -setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='contras' -enableRule:AppOffline -retryAttempts:6 -retryInterval:10000 -enableRule:DoNotDeleteRule -userAgent:VSTS_7c1c6e1c-7491-4898-bc4d-a85345921032_Release__16_26_1
2019-05-21T13:09:59.9100098Z Info: Using ID 'fe8253d8-98f3-4403-9e0d-98ceb9f2a406' for connections to the remote server.
2019-05-21T13:10:11.3653059Z Total changes: 0 (0 added, 0 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed, 0 bytes copied)
2019-05-21T13:10:11.4450004Z Updating App Service Application settings. Data: {"CloudVersion":"1.4.2"}
2019-05-21T13:10:22.5003712Z Updated App Service Application settings and Kudu Application settings.
2019-05-21T13:10:26.5732176Z Successfully updated App Service configuration details
2019-05-21T13:10:33.4106055Z Successfully updated deployment History at https://contras-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/161558444226571
2019-05-21T13:10:33.4184229Z App Service Application URL: http://contras-staging.azurewebsites.net
2019-05-21T13:10:33.4378162Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure App Service Deploy: contras
```

Comment: Then I tried the zip deploy option, but it gives me the error: Publish using zip deploy option is not supported for msBuild package type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it here...The solution/problem lay in the VS solution, which resulted in an invalid zip content.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/587989/azure-devops-release-pipeline-azure-app-service-fi.html